Lyx creating too much space in in-line code before maths symbols
I use code in Lyx documents (Text Style -> Code). I need to enable Logical Markup to enable this.
In-line code works fine usually but with unusual characters like ℕ, the output seems to create too much space.
The following is an example: The text {a : ℕ} is entered inside an inline code section. The following shows the large space before the ℕ in the output PDF. It also shows the correct spacing for non-inline code sections (listings).
Anyone know how to fix this?
I don't do direct LaTeX so prefer Lyx only solutions.
The following are the warnings from "check tex" in the Lyx menu. I don't think they're relevant.
01_first_proof.tex:3:18:18:Use either `` or '' as an alternative to `"'.
01_first_proof.tex:3:61:18:Use either `` or '' as an alternative to `"'.
01_first_proof.tex:109:20:26:You ought to remove spaces in front of punctuation.
01_first_proof.tex:111:29:26:You ought to remove spaces in front of punctuation.



UPDATE
This is a minimal tex file exported from Lyx.
%% LyX 2.3.8 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,english]{scrbook}
\usepackage{berasans}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setstretch{1.1}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\providecommand*{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{keywordcolor}{rgb}{0.7, 0.1, 0.1}   % red
\definecolor{tacticcolor}{rgb}{0.0, 0.1, 0.6}    % blue
\definecolor{commentcolor}{rgb}{0.4, 0.4, 0.4}   % grey
\definecolor{symbolcolor}{rgb}{0.0, 0.1, 0.6}    % blue
\definecolor{sortcolor}{rgb}{0.1, 0.5, 0.1}      % green
\definecolor{attributecolor}{rgb}{0.7, 0.1, 0.1} % red

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Listing}

\begin{document}
The quick brown fox.

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},frame=lines,aboveskip={\bigskipamount},escapechar={\%},language={lean}]
-- 01 - First Proof

import Mathlib.Tactic

example {a: %$\mathbb{{N}}$%} (h1: a = 4) : a > 1 := by
  calc
    a = 4 := by rw [h1]
    _ > 1 := by norm_num
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{itemize}
\item The \code{\{a : \ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}\}} tells Lean that the variable
\code{a} is a natural number. 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}

And here is the pdf output from running pdflatex on the tex file.


Please always post a minimal example .lyx file (see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample). And although you want a LyX solution, I suggest you still post the .tex file of the minimal example. The reason for that is that people like me (I know LyX but I'm not a LaTeX expert) and non-LyX LaTeX experts can work together to figure out a solution for you. Specifically, I won't be able to fix this, but if you post the .tex someone might provide a LaTeX solution and I can try to figure out a LyX solution from that.

related: https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/13076#comment:2
